# How to convert SQL query millisecondsSinceEpoch integer to DateTime in Dart?

Tags: sql, flutter, dart

dateTime is stored as an INTEGER, how do I turn each row into Darts DateTime object without wasting time?

```
query = await db.rawQuery(
              '''SELECT dateTime FROM days WHERE (dateTime BETWEEN ${start.millisecondsSinceEpoch} AND ${end.millisecondsSinceEpoch})''');
```

I want this query to return a map/list of DateTime insted of milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

why not just :

- fetch all data
- for each data convert it into a DateTime, like this :

```
DateTime day = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(data['timestamp_day']);
```